# Why some variables need quotes and othes dont

Tags: php, mysql

Why do some variables need quotes and others don't? Example when I connect to the DB Variables dont need quotes but when I select or insert into a DB I need quotes.

Example:

```
//variables
    $username="username";
    $password="password";
    $first=$_POST['first'];
    $last=$_POST['last'];

//connect to DB
   mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
   @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to connect to database");

//values assigned
    $query = "INSERT INTO guestbook VALUES           
    ('','$first','$last','$email','$web','$comment')";
    mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Could you please clear up your question it is not very clear. Also your example is not very clear as well.

Comment: When I connected to my database I stared to use quotes around $username. When I insert the values such as $first, I needed to put quotes. Why do some vaiables need quotes and others dont?

Comment: This is not a safe way to do database queries.  Once you get a handle on the basics read about SQL injection, and the prepare/bind method, which you can do in PHP using either mysqli or PDO.

Comment: I know, I am learning but variables are a bit confusing. I thought all variables need quotes and that is why I had trouble connecting. I have used mysql_connect(localhost,'$username','$password'); and it did not like that idea. Or is it something that you learn over time of what gets quotes and what dosn't?

Comment: @Jordan You only need quotes if you are creating a new string, e.g.: `"foo"`. Variables ***never need*** quotes. You *may* use variables inside a string literal, so its value will get interpolated: `"foo $bar baz"`. But `"$foo"` is *always* unnecessary, since it simply creates a new string whose only content is the content of a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a string literal: `"username"`. It is a *value*.
This is a *variable*: `$username`. It can hold any *value*. Think of it as a placeholder.
This is a *variable* inside a string literal: `"foo $username bar"`. It creates a new *value*.

When creating SQL queries, you simply pass a string to the database, which it will parse according to SQL syntax rules. SQL syntax requires that you put quotes around certain parts. It has nothing to do with PHP variables.

Further, this is a constant: `localhost`. You do not have a constant of that name defined, it is actually an error that PHP recovers from by creating the string `'localhost'` from it on the fly. It is actually an error though.

Read about these individual parts of the PHP syntax: http://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php.

---

You only need quotes if you are creating a new string, e.g.: `"foo"`. Variables ***never*** need quotes. You may use variables inside a string literal, so its value will get interpolated: `"foo $bar baz"`. But `"$foo"` is always unnecessary, since it simply creates a new string whose only content is the content of a variable.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confusing PHP variables:

```
$username = "bobby tables";
```

with [string interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation#PHP):

```
$interp = "foo $username bar";
```

The former assigns the string `"bobby tables"` to the variable `$username`, and the latter assigns the string `"foo bobby tables bar"` to the variable `$interp`.

Comment: See also: PHP [variable parsing](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing). `"one " . $two` vs. `"one $two"` vs. `"one {$two}"`.

Comment: Ok I will take a look at this, and this looks like it could be tricky as well.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

PHP interprets certain sequences of characters as undefined constants, and treats them as strings.

```
$ php -r 'var_dump(OH_YEAH);'
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant OH_YEAH - assumed 'OH_YEAH' in Command line code on line 1
string(6) "OH_YEAH"
```

So `localhost` in your call to `mysql_connect()` is parsed as a constant and evaluated just as `"localhost"` would be.

Answer (score 1):

The variables inside your query (a string variable) need quotes to make them readable as variables. If you don't add the quotes you will insert the names of the variables instead of the variables values itself.
The reason you don't have to do this when you connect to the database is simply because you don't use a string variable there.

Comment: Thank you, this makes more sense

Comment: Wut? You mean you need the `'` in `"('$first')"` to "make the variable readable"? If you actually mean *that*, that's complete nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

The correct code for inserting the content of the variables into the database is like this:

```
    //variables
$username="username";
$password="password";
$first=$_POST['first'];
$last=$_POST['last'];

    //connect to DB
mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to connect to database");

    //values assigned
$query = "INSERT INTO guestbook VALUES           
('','.$first.','.$last.','.$email.','.$web.','.$comment.')";
mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mixing up PHP and Mysql.  For PHP you don't need quotes for variables.

```
mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
```

If I understand correctly your getting confused on:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO guestbook VALUES ('','$first','$last','$email','$web','$comment')";
```

The reason you need quotes around these variables is because it's mySQL syntax, not PHP.  You will get an error if you do this in mysql:

```
"INSERT INTO guestbook VALUES ('',$first,$last,$email,$web,$comment)";
```

The reason is because the PHP variable is converted to it's value for mySQL, and mysql will read those values the same way it reads guestbook, causing an error.

Also, when I started, it took me a while to grasp the difference in php quotes:
"  can have php variables inside like so:

```
$name = "Eric"; 
echo "this is $name"; // prints  this is Eric
```

but if you use ' instead of "  you'll get: this is $name
' is a string literal.  if you use ' and actually want the variable, you need to escape it like so:

```
echo 'this is \$name';
```

vis versa for " if you want it to print out $name instead of Eric, you do:

```
echo "this is \$name";
```

Hope this clarifies, and keep learning PHP!

Comment: `'this is \$name'` → this is \$name